# Mongoose Unit testing - is it necessary to test the saving process?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mocha.js

I am currently writing some mocha tests for Mongoose models.
I was wondering, if it is really necessary to test the whole saving process.

(pseudo-codish):

```
let modelInstance = new Model(specs);
modelInstance.save();
modelInstance.find(selector, function(err, res){
  compare(specs, res);
});
```

Wouldn't it be enough to just create an instance and check if that instance is fine? Isn't it guaranteed by mongoose that the saving process itself works? Or is there anything I need to pay attention to?

Comment: You can validate the document without saving it, which allows you to test if the schema validation is working correctly. However, indexes may or may not work in some cases, even though the document passes the validator. For example, if you have a unique index or 2dphere index, there's no way for the client side validation to know if the index will or won't return an error during the insert.

Comment: @BrianShamblen So I suppose I should unit test the whole saving process, right?